# How do I know where on disk a module is being loaded from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, commonjs

I have a module `@vendorname/functions` that does not exist on the filesystem according to `npm list`

```
$ npm ls @vendorname/functions
serverless-commerce@1.0.0 C:\Users\mikem\OneDrive\Documents\myapp\myapp
`-- (empty)
```

It also does not exist according to a demo file:

```
$ node
> require("@vendorname/functions")
{ Error: Cannot find module '@vendorname/functions'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

However I have a piece of software in the parent folder `C:\Users\mikem\OneDrive\Documents\myapp\myapp` that uses the module and it works:

```
let vendornameFunctions = require("@vendorname/functions"),

log(`>>> MYSTERY FILE IS BEING IMPORTED ${JSON.dumps(vendornameFunctions, null, 2)}`);
```

Returns:

```
>>> MYSTERY FILE IS BEING IMPORTED {
    "events": {},
    "queues": {},
    "tables": {},
    "html": {},
    "json": {},
    "css": {},
    "js": {},
    "text": {},
    "xml": {}
}
```

I can reliably replicate this behavior. **How can I determine where on disk the module is being loaded from?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`require.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) to get the path to the module.

```
console.log(require.resolve("@vendorname/functions"));
```

Comment: Thanks Dan - not just for the working answer but also actually reading the question! 